# email in laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use `Mail` function in Laravel. Heres the code

```
public function basic_email(){
  $data = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi");

  Mail::send(['text'=>'mail'], $data, function($message) {
     $message->to('shanipasrooria@gmail.com', 'Tutorials Point')->subject
        ('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
     $message->from('m.usman5991@gmail.com','Virat Gandhi');
  });

  echo "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
 }
```

I have made changes in `.env` file. Set everything, Heres my `route`.
`Route::get('sendbasicemail','MailController@basic_email');`

I get the following Error.

`InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [mail] not found.`

Comment: In your showed errors not come in `Email sending`. It is result of wrong view structure

Comment: Theres no view assigned. why this error then?@Davit

Comment: If you comment Mail sending error occurs??

Comment: I do not understand, what  should I comment? @Davit

Comment: comment line 5-9

Comment: I commented the whole `Mail` function, no error appeared. @Davit

Comment: I used this code, and it work perfect. You can try it `Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
            $message->to('shanipasrooria@gmail.com', 'Tutorials Point')
                ->subject('subject')
                ->setBody('some body', 'text/html');
        });`

Comment: I am getting error, `Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b6-v6sm18000832wru.66 - gsmtp
"`

Comment: @Davit my username and password are correct.

Comment: I think theres some problem with my google privacy, thank you very much. How do I mark your answer as accepted? @Davit

Comment: I dont answered your question. I only try help you

Comment: it  worked, sir. thank you very much. please write the code in answer. @Davit

Comment: I added a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) { 
    $message->to('shanipasrooria@gmail.com', 'Tutorials Point')
       ->subject('subject') 
       ->setBody('some body', 'text/html'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$html = '<h1>Hi, welcome Virat!</h1>';
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($html) {
  $message->to('shanipasrooria@gmail.com', 'Tutorials Point')
          ->subject('Laravel Basic Testing Mail')
          ->from('m.usman5991@gmail.com','Virat Gandhi')
          ->setBody($html, 'text/html'); //html body
           or
          ->setBody('Hi, welcome Virat!'); //for text body
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mail::send(['text'=>'mail']`< here the `mail` should be a valid view file.

Answer (score 0):

According to API Documentation, the Mailer Class should receive a String, Array Or MailableContract, Those reference a view. So you need to pass a valid view in the `send` method.

```
void send(string|array|MailableContract $view, array $data = [], Closure|string $callback = null)
```